# Exporting All features in view extent using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: export, arcgis-pro

Is there an easy way to export selected features, or features in the current map extent, to a File Geodatabase?

In ArcMap, I can export data from a single layer, and select *All features in view extent*, but this option does not seem to be available in Pro. The tools on the *Share* tab all seem to export entire featureclasses.

If possible, I would like to export data from multiple layers at once, and also include relationshipclasses between the features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Environments tab of Copy Features (right-click layer and export) and choose Current Display Extent:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I also found *Analysis > Tools > Data Management Tools > Package > Package Map*. This allows you to export features from all layers, for a given extent, to a File Geodatabase. Unfortunately it breaks on related records with *Cannot reset foreign key values for an existing relationship row*, so I guess I need to export all layers separately.

Answer (score 0):

I inadvertently found a way to do this with points from 6 different data shapefiles. After selecting points by location, I used Tools/Geoprocessing/Merge and included “add source information to output” so the source data were appended to the table. Only the highlighted points were merged.